# ShowcaseView on top of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, showcaseview

I am using [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview) in an Android App. I want to be able to display the `ShowcaseView` on top of a `DialogFragment`. But for me, the `ShowcaseView` is displaying underneath the `DialogFragment`.

There are open issues on this subject on github for this project. But I thought that I would ask here as was suggested. [This](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/issues/139) post mentioned that he solved the issue "using a fake activity as a dialogfragment."  But I am not sure what that means. Maybe that means that instead of using a `DialogFragment`, he used an `Activity` and is displaying it as a `DialogFragment`? I know that you can set the theme of an activity to be a Dialog in the Manifest: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`.

The other github issues are [here](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/issues/132) and [here](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/issues/173).

I am using the "legacy" version of `ShowcaseView` like this:

```
ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.imageView, getActivity());
ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(target, getActivity(), R.string.showcase_title, R.string.showcase_details);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get `ShowcaseView` to display properly on a `DialogFragment`, we have to show the `DialogFragment` as a `Fragment` instead of showing the `DialogFragment` as a `Dialog`.

In the `DialogFragment`, we could have something like this:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
    return new MyDialogFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
    View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ((TextView)tv).setText("This is an instance of MyDialogFragment");
    return v;
}
```

That we could show it in an Activity like this:

```
public class MyDialogActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_manager);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        MyDialogFragment fragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, "Some_tag")
            .commit();
    }
}
```

activity_contact_manager.xml layout could be:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml entry could be:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MyDialogActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I am using a plain old `Dialog`. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, it will only skip the problem and will not work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should write add a method, change `Activity` to `DialogFragment`

```
private void show(DialogFragment dialog) {
    ((ViewGroup) dialog.getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this);
}
```

It's working for me.