# Why is my showcaseview showing behind my bottomsheetdialog in android?

Tags: java, android, showcaseview

I am trying to show a `showcase` inside my `bottomsheetdialog`, as shown in my code below:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
report.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_dialog_layout);

    EditText report_bill_type = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bll);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((Color.TRANSPARENT)));
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    new GuideView.Builder(v.getContext())
        .setTitle("Title here")
        .setContentText("Description here")
        .setGravity(smartdevelop.ir.eram.showcaseviewlib.config.Gravity.auto)
        .setTargetView(report_bill_type) //showcase keeps showing behind the dialog
        .setDismissType(DismissType.anywhere)
        .build()
        .show();
});
```

When I execute the code, the `showcase` keeps showing behind the dialog. How do I resolve this issue?

I am using [this](https://github.com/mreram/ShowCaseView) showcase view.

Comment: In the issues section of the project you are using, I searched "dialog" and there is an [issue][1] similar to your problem. this [workaround][2] may be helpful.


  [1]: https://github.com/mreram/ShowCaseView/issues/27
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896656/showcaseview-on-top-of-dialogfragment

Comment: @mrzbn I had already checked the posts you mentioned, unlike them I am not using a `DialogFragment`, I am using just a simple `Dialog`. So I am unsure as to how to resolve this.

Comment: I would suggest either to replace library to the similar alternative or go deep inside lib source code and fix this bug. Both solutions has their pros and cons. Anyway, submitting bug report to the origin repo is good and might help to solve this issue faster.